# how to get the color of NSWindow's title bar, especially when the window lose focus?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, nswindow

I made my own toolbar in my project, but the color of the toolbar is not matched with the title bar of the window.
in OS X, when a window lose focus, its title bar will change color, how to get that color?

I tried to use _Window.backgroundColor(), NSColor.headerColor(), NSColor.windowBackgroundColor()..  None of them works.

Comment: I still don't know an easier way to get the color  dynamically, but i solved my problem by putting my toolbar inside the NSWindow's title bar, then make my toolbar transparent.  So it will use the title bar's color.  Works pretty well.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by putting my toolbar inside the NSWindow's title bar, then make my toolbar transparent. So it will use the title bar's color. Works pretty well. Thanks guys

[[[NSWindow contentView] superview] addSubview:MyCustomToolbar]

Answer (score 0):

You can pick the exact RGB values of any component from `Digital Color Meter` present as a default application in  you Mac.

After getting the RGB values you can use

```
NSColor *loseFocusColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:redValue green:greenValue blue:blueValue alpha:1.0f];
```

This cannot be done if the title bar has a gradient instead of one single color

Comment: Thank you Kaunteya, as you said, this way worked for non gradient color.  But I would prefer to not hard code the color.  I have a function that takes a point on screen and return me the color at that point, so i can pass in a point that's a little bit above the title bar to color dynamically. Since I am getting the bottom color, even it's gradient it doesn't looks so bad.. But I still don't like this way for many reasons.